# How do I test if my opencv_traincascade is still training and not stuck at a stage?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to train my cascade with the following parameters:

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier5 -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt -numStages 13 -featureType LBP -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000 -numNeg 600 -w 24 -h 24 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 512 -precalcIdxBufSize 512

PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: classifier5
vecFileName: samples.vec
bgFileName: negatives.txt
numPos: 1000
numNeg: 600
numStages: 13
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 512
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 512
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
```

The first 4 stages took like 20 second but now it's been running at stage 5 for an hour. I want to check if the it is not stuck and still running.